# Getting weird result from Solr query

Tags: cassandra, solr, lucene, datastax-enterprise

I am using Datastax 6.8. This is my SOLR schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
  <types>
    <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
    <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="NameField">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="15" minGramSize="2"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="15" minGramSize="2"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
  </types>
  <fields>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="nama" type="StrField"/>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="nama_copy" type="NameField"/>
  </fields>
  <uniqueKey>(nama)</uniqueKey>
  <copyField dest="nama_copy" source="nama"/>
</schema>
```

I have this field value in a row **batamindo v**

Then I ran this query:

```
http://my_ip_address:8983/solr/search.form/select?wt=json&indent=true&fl=nama&q=nama_copy:batamindo\ v
```

I got very nice result

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":8},
  "response":{"numFound":579,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "nama":"BATAMINDO V "},
      {
        "nama":"BATAMINDO V"},
      {
        "nama":"BATAMINDO V"},
      {
        "nama":"BATAMINDO V"},
      {
        "nama":"BATAMINDO V"},
      {
        "nama":"BATAMINDO V"},
      {
        "nama":"BATAMINDO V"},
      {
        "nama":"BATAMINDO V"},
      {
        "nama":"BATAMINDO V"},
      {
        "nama":"BATAMINDO V"}]
  }}
```

But when I ran

```
http://my_ip_address:8983/solr/search.form/select?wt=json&indent=true&fl=nama&q=nama_copy:batamindo\ vi
```

My search result is very bad

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":14},
  "response":{"numFound":602,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "nama":"MV. VINCA"},
      {
        "nama":"MV. VINASHIP PEARL"},
      {
        "nama":"MV. VINASHIP PEARL"},
      {
        "nama":"MV. VINCENT TRADER"},
      {
        "nama":"MV. MEGHNA VICTORY"},
      {
        "nama":"MV. MEGHNA VICTORY"},
      {
        "nama":"NAVI SUNNY"},
      {
        "nama":"MV. MEGHNA VICTORY"},
      {
        "nama":"MT. GOLDEN VIOLET"},
      {
        "nama":"MT. GOLDEN VIOLET"}]
  }}
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Your query contains two words. That's expected behaviour. Are you looking for an exact match query?

Comment: Your `NameField` type has an ngram filter attached - this means that any substring of the tokens will be indexed as well, and in this case, that means that `VINCA` gets indexed as `vi`, `in`, `nc`, `ca`, `vin`, (etc.) `vinc`, `vinca` - and since you're searching with a string that contains `vi` as well (you're doing the same on the query side, so `batamindo\ vi` gets the same treatment, where one of the tokens generated will be `vi` - and you get a match. You'll probably get better results by only doing this ngram expansion on the indexing side, depending on what you want the result to be.

Comment: How about using KeywordTokenizerFactory instead of LowerCaseTokenizerFactory?

Comment: KeywordTokenizerFactory will make another search inaccurate, in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is expected behaviour.

The `NGramFilterFactory` class tokenises strings into grams of N size. In your case, the strings are broken up into grams of 2 to 15 characters based on your schema definition of:

```
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="15" minGramSize="2"/>
```

For an input string like `cassandra`, the N-gram filter generates the following grams:

- size=2 : `ca as ss sa an nd dr ra`
- size=3 : `cas ass ssa san and ndr dra`
- size=4 : `cass assa ssan sand andr ndra`
- and so on until size=15

For search term `ss`, the Solr query will get a match for `ss`, `ass`, `ssa`, `assa`, `ssan` and so on.

In your case where the search term is `vi`, it is expected to match `vinca`, `vinaship`, `vincent`, `victory`, `navi`, `violet` and so on.

For more information, see [Document Analysis in Solr](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/filters.html#n-gram-filter). Cheers!

Comment: When I search "batamindo\ vi", why SOLR didn't count batamindo which has more "character match" instead of vi compared to vinca?

Comment: How do you know it didn't "count" it?

Comment: When I search "batamindo vi", naturally "batamindo v" is more similar than "vinca". So I am hoping to get "batamindo v" as result.

By the way I got fixed this issue by tuning the N-Gram maxSize to 4. I got better search result by this configuration.

Comment: In response to "... I am hoping to get 'batamindo v' as result ...", it is still part of the result but it just didn't get displayed in the first page. Cheers!

Comment: Erick, do you work at Datastax? My company is DSE customer, but somehow I got better service here from you instead from support.datastax.com

Comment: Yes, I do -- I've disclosed it in my profile.  And thanks for the feedback. If you'd like to give me the ticket ID, I would be happy to discuss with the team. Cheers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254929/discussion-between-panoet-and-erick-ramirez).